# PHP using DELETE FROM to remove row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

Below is the code I  have been trying to use to delete a row from my mysql database. I have been searching through the forum and I have yet find the issue. I know my connection is working properly as I have been able to use the INSERT INTO command with no problems. I'm sure it's pretty obvious that I am new to this, looking for simple solution.

```
<?php

$_POST[title];
$jimmy = $_POST[title];
echo $jimmy;    ## this echo is here to make sure I was getting form data sent over      correctly
include("dogs.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname)
         or die("Couldn't connect to server");

$sql = "DELETE FROM ashly3 WHERE title = '$jimmy' " ;
mysqli_query( $cxn, $sql );

include("ashly.php");


?>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Are you sure there's a row with title matching the value of `$jimmy`? Also please sanitize your user input.

Comment: Ah, it's `$jimmy`, come on in, `$jimmy`, [little bobby tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) is expecting you.

Comment: try changing this `mysqli_query( $cxn, $sql );` to `mysqli_query( $cxn, $sql ) or die('Error performing query');`

Comment: @Ibrahim die(mysqli_error()) to get the actual error message that is provided by mysql. Also change `$_POST[title]` to `$_POST["title"]` unless you have `define`d `title` to be a constant. It seems you have turned off error_reporting and/or display_errors. See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php to enable it.

Comment: Please quote your array keys. Though PHP will correctly interpret the unquoted strings (which are undefined constants) as strings, it is poor practice to rely on this behavior. Plus it loads up your logs with notices.  `$_POST["title"]` instead of `$_POST[title]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jimmy = $_POST[title];
```

Should be

```
$jimmy = $_POST['title'];
```

But that's not the reason it doesn't work, PHP should fix that error for you with a warning.

Also, inserting text from the `$_POST` without escaping is going to cause you trouble with SQL injection. Imagine if the user inserts `hello' OR 1` into the title text field. Use http://phptutorial.info/?mysqli.real-escape-string

Comment: I put the quote in, with no success, like you thought. The php files are controlled by host, so may take it bit to get that fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider using PDO for databases.
Anyways, for your solution, to identify the error: Try this:
    mysqli_query( $cxn, $sql )or die(mysqli_error());

Also, please use mysqli_real_escape_string() around your user input :)

Comment: Can you give me an idea of the code you think I should use? Thanks for the help.

Comment: After you've connected to your database with PDO, you could do like:
$sql = "delete from `sample_tbl` where `dtl_name`= :dtl_name"; $param[':dtl_name'] = array($dtlname, PDO::PARAM_STR); $result = $db->query($sql, $param);

Answer (score 1):

i think your error is $_POST[title] should be $_POST['title'] , anyway try this code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//$_POST[title];
$jimmy = $_POST['title'];
echo $jimmy;    ## this echo is here to make sure I was getting form data sent over      correctly
include("dogs.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbname)
         or die("Couldn't connect to server");

$sql = 'DELETE FROM `ashly3` WHERE title = \''.mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$jimmy).'\'';

$retval=mysqli_query( $cxn, $sql );
echo "retval:";var_dump($retval);
if($retval===false)
{
echo "mysqli_error:";var_dump(mysqli_error($cxn));
}
include("ashly.php");


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be this, it is working for me

```
<?php
require '../access/dbaccess.php';
$dtlname=  $_POST['remove_dtlname'];
mysql_query("delete from `sample_tbl` where `dtl_name`='$dtlname'");
?>
```

Where dbaccess.php is

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('<your server>', '<username>', '<password>');
        if (!$link)
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('btp');
?>
```

Comment: He is using `mysqli` and your code is trivially vulnerable to SQL injection. I wouldn't suggest this to a newcomer.

Comment: yup ,I know this is simple .. just suggesting a technique like this might work

Comment: then for the love of http://xkcd.com/327 please sanitize the user input `$dtlname=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['remove_dtlname']);`. we don't teach with flawed examples.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the code you wrote here. Again, I am very new to this, trying to learn. Any simpler examples would be appreciated. thanks for the effort

Answer (score -1):

Try breaking out the variable out of the $SQL line:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ashly3 WHERE title = '".$jimmy."' " ;
```

Comment: It wouldn't. Waste of a comment.

Comment: This might help because it makes things a little clearer. It could also cause the $variable to become a literal name i.e puts in the string "$jimmy".

Comment: This syntax does not make anything clearer, it makes it awful to look at, if you know anything about PHP string interpolation, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double .Both syntaxes do exactly the same thing, and the interpolation is much nicer to the eyes